# Why are the good guys in my world hurting other people against their will to extend their own lives?

Tags: culture, immortality, philosophy

For the benefit of anyone who sees this and has a similar question.  It seems like I should have asked this elsewhere.  Maybe writing se or something.

The problem I'm trying to solve: a faction is prolonging their own lives and harming unwilling or unwitting innocents to do so.  I want them to have a really good reason for doing so.

Context: I have a partially formulated homebrew world with a high fantasy, sword and sorcery, European romance setting.

What I'm trying to accomplish:  A solution that will turn an audience from "I hate these guys" to "Oh!  They're not all bad." on a big curtain-draw reveal of the actual motivation of the big bad faction.

Why?  It would be cool to have a very hateable faction turn out to be good guys that didn't really WANT to prolong their lives at the cost of making others suffer.

The best possible answer I could hope for would jar an audience with maximum moral realization u-turn, and explain why the faction had **no other choice** but to prolong the life/conciousness of one or more of their specific members.

**Research**: I've looked to try and find things like un-ubjectionable reasons for character to prolong their lives (beyond the effects of a healthy lifestyle) in existing media and found that people who cause harm for their own immortality are almost universally the-bad-guy.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134558/discussion-on-question-by-brent-hackers-why-on-moral-grounds-might-a-faction-t).

Comment: What if the exchange rate was actually really good. The basic rules of magic say someone must be sacrificed to extend the lives of others. So they find someone who is on their deathbed anyway, and sacrifice them in a way that gives a whole town full of people 50 years of healthy life.

Comment: @DonaldHobson I actually had no intention to have anyone die as a result.  Just maybe imprisoned and made very uncomfortable and maybe having their heads messed with a bit.  Kinda like being stuck in one place for a few years while being bombarded with misleading messages and having to work in uncomfortable conditions so a bunch of dudes can live longer.

Comment: I recommend you to read the first Mistborn trilogy by Brandon Sanderson, if you can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's magic, right? The protagonist is the "Chosen One", through magic he has trapped a terrible demon, held at bay by the strength of his soul. If he dies, the demon is released and will murder tens of thousands.

With great age his soul is losing it's grip on the demon. It tires and is ready for rest before moving on to a new life. The only way to strengthen his soul is by ritual sacrifice.

He must find the new Chosen One, but despite his repeated attempts at divination (also costly to his soul), the Chosen One has not been revealed to him (as he was revealed to his aged predecessor).

At the cost of the few lives (he chooses criminals, perhaps), he is saving tens of thousands of lives, until he can transfer responsibility for the demon to the next Chosen One.

If you like, this can all be a closely held secret as well, known only to his sorcerer and closest confidants.

EDITS: Okay, I re-read your edited post. I'd say some souls are strong, some are weak. Anytime you have any variation whatsoever, you have maximums and minimums. The entity being controlled is the King Goblin, a very strong evil soul. The King Goblin is the only one that can organize all goblins into an army, by force of his evil Will. Otherwise they are just anarchic evil on their own.

Our hero has an even stronger soul than the King Goblin, and can hold him captive somehow. Perhaps even feed it just enough soul to keep it alive.

But, regardless of physical health, our hero's soul ages and grows weak over centuries. It can be transferred to a new body, but it still ages. Eventually, our hero must find a replacement, someone born with a fresh soul that has strength that exceeds their own.

As for why weak souls are consumed, I can think of a few possibilities, but here is one.

Say our hero must periodically feed the King Goblin "soul food", because if that thing dies, the next strongest Goblin soul becomes the new King, organizes a Goblin Army and wreaks havoc.

But all our hero needs is the body, after magically extracting the victim's soul, our hero can transfer their own soul into the younger body. Because again, if the body housing our hero's soul dies, the King Goblin is released.

A weird alternative: The hero actually melds his soul with that of the King Goblin; they are "wed" in some magical sense. But the hero's soul and will is stronger than the Goblin's soul; and prevents it from commanding its armies.

The problem is still that if the Hero's body dies, both souls die or ascend or whatever; the wedding is over. And the next strongest Goblin becomes King, with the unrestrained ability to command its armies; while among humans, nobody knows who has a soul strong enough to capture the soul of this new King Goblin.

Comment: This helps.  Prevention of greater suffering because of a specific task/knowledge/whatever that would be difficult or impossible sor a group to pass down to a new generation is exactly what I am looking for, although I may not have expressed this well...

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure about the soul thing but I like the idea about somehow trying to justify a specific group having to be around to try keep a big bad from being replaced by a far worse bad, possibly even saying that this is necessary because this group are the only ones that can keep bad in check because of some kind of contract with or preference of the big bad.  So accepting as I think this'll get me where I need to be eventually.

Answer (score 4):

**Duty**

The character in question has a duty which no one else can perform.  It could be a duty known to the public (e.g., he's the last wizard powerful enough to keep the volcano from erupting) or it could be a private obligation (e.g. he refuses to die until he has avenged himself on the dragon that killed his father).  There are a million ways to go with this, but certainly if his actions are "justifiable" there must be something he has to *do* here on Earth that justifies it, at least to himself.

Answer (score 2):

**It is always the rule that nation protects its leaders**

Leaders of the nation are always protected. This protection may cost regular servicemen and bodyguards their lives, but the consensus is that the people who protect the leader may have to sacrifice themselves. And this is not viewed as selfish for the leaders. Leading the nation is a great burden, so people of the nation accept this sacrifice. Sometimes those sacrifices are unwilling, for example when enemy detonates a bomb which kills everyone in range except the leader who is protected by bulletproof glass. This still looks all right and even brave and noble, because it is the leader who was the  target of the attack.

Answer (score 2):

By our moral standards, and by corollary the morality in most of our fiction, this:

> and to some extent this goal will be possible at the expense of **unwilling sacrifices.**

(emphasis mine) seems incompatible with this:

> But I'd like a thematically suitable, and genuine, noble, idealistic, and even justifiable reason for these characters to do so.

By most fantasy logic the act of stealing life by unwilling sacrifice is inherently evil and as such is a corrupting force that will eventually turn even the most pure and noble of goals towards darkness and villainy. If your noble ancients are aware of the source of their life extension then they should naturally (by fantasy standards) trend towards either evil or insanity.

So let's not tell them about it. Whatever their duty, whatever their requirements, it's better that they stay pure and unsullied by the horrible necessities behind their longevity. Instead we'll train generations of special priests and mages who are tasked with the less savory aspects of the process. We don't mind if they go mad from their actions, they are doing good work by doing evil. Oh we'll give them a flashy-sounding title, treat them well and indoctrinate them well, and of course they never talk to the Ancient Ones - that's reserved for the support teams whose purpose is purely to keep the ancients in peak spritual, mental and moral condition.

And of course it's important that nobody else know about these special workers. Nothing can be allowed to leak out, it's all terribly secret and it just wouldn't do if some hint of their activities was to come to the awareness of the Ancients. Last time that happened it took months to clean up the mess and convince them that it was all lies spread by our enemies.

So we have a secret society with a core of well-protected - and controlled - assasins, dark priests and black mages who do the dirty work of keeping the rituals powered and operating correctly to extend the life of our Ancient Protectors. Another group of mages and priests focus on masking the nature of the rituals, and a third group who act as servants and filters for the Ancients themselves. All bound into the structure of The Church.

And of course we pay a lot of attention to image at all levels. Just because they're doing distasteful work there's no reason why our special members should look disreputable. Oh the procurement lads do tend to dress dark while they're working, can't have all that silver thread and white silk giving them away, but we don't go in for dark and smokey rooms, skeletal wall hangings and the other trappings of evil magics. We're a reputable group doing unpleasant things so that our Protectors aren't sullied. Nobody wants a repeat of the Immortal Dark Lord fiasco, do we.

Answer (score 2):

## Having a brilliant mind

This person or people is/are insanely smart. So smart that their contributions to a science/engineering/medicine/magic, probably/whatever field can advance civilization far beyond what it is now. Of course, death is inevitable, and you may need just a bit more time to come up with the latest discovery. What is the expense of one person or a few people to benefit all of humanity? It's a tragic sacrifice, but all people, from the richest nobles to the poorest peasants, will benefit from this mind staying alive, just a little bit longer.

I dont know the limitations of your magic system, so it is possible that the need for medicine, science, or engineering can be replaced by magic, magic, or magic. If it is somewhat limited, like few people can have magic or magic can only do so much, then this is perfect. If many people have magic, and magic can do a whole lot, then not so much.

Answer (score 0):

**Prophecy**

The prophecy is that Grand Patriarch Chad will be the last Grand Patriarch of the Church.  Chad and his people take that to mean that somehow the Church will crumble or dissolve with his passing.  We can't have that!  So Chad endures, that the Church will endure.

A prophecy is interpreted in such a way that the continuance of the leader (pope, king, etc) means the continuance of the nation or church.  Of course the prophecy is true if the pope or king continues indefinitely.